# Run scrapyd in Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, scrapyd, scrapyd-deploy

I've been looking around and I can't seem  to find an answer on how to run scrapyd in Python 3 and above. When I run it it keeps defaulting to python 2.7, though I recall reading in the docs or elsewhere that scrapyd supports python3:
https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/news.html#id1

Running on an AWS Ubuntu 18.04 server. What am I doing wrong? How can I change to Python 3.4 and above?

I'm having problems because I'm using abstract inheritance in my spiders which python 2.7 doesn't support.

Edit: I'm able to run Scrapyd in Python 3 using a virtual environment, but how would you do it without one?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is use a virtual enviroment.

Since you are using Ubuntu and you can make it work using a venv I assume you installed scrapy using `pip` instead of `pip3`. Since Py2.7 is the stardard reference to python in Ubuntu, when running pip it will execute pip for py2 instead of py3.

Another way would be uninstalling `pip uninstall scrapy` and installing it again using pip3 `pip3 install scrapy`. This should fix the reference to scrapy. If by any chance you also use scrapy in py2.7 and therefore can't uninstall, then you have another reason to use venv.